# Flutter ListView not updating

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I wanted to create a ListView in Flutter that update when new data arrives. I am using a RefreshIndicator that triggers the list loading for testing. For my list I am using a ListBuilder to map my objects to view objects.

From what I understand, the setState() should trigger an update to my list, however it does not.

Debugging showed that my _listContent is actually filled with 72 items after when the setState() callback is called. Why does my list not auto update? Am I missing something?

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Manga> _listContent = new List<Manga>();

    void _addMangas(List<Manga> mangas) {
      setState(() {
        _listContent.addAll(mangas);
        print('Cleared list');
        });
    }

    Future<Null> _onRefresh() {
      Completer<Null> completer = new Completer<Null>();

      loadMangaItems().then((mangas) => _addMangas(mangas));
      completer.complete();

      return completer.future;
    }

    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(

        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new RefreshIndicator(
          child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: _listContent.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
                Manga manga = _listContent[index];
                return new MangaItem(
                  name: manga.writtenName,
                  number: manga.currentNr,
                  state: false,
                );
              }),
          onRefresh: _onRefresh),
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a question about this implementation of the RefreshCallback (_onRefresh()). Isn't `completer.complete();` being called here *before* the loadMangaItems() completes?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out the problem was that

```
List<Manga> _listContent = new List<Manga>();
```

was defined on top of widget.build and not on top of the State class. Defining it like this works fine:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<Manga> _listContent = new List<Manga>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: You can also move _addMangas and _onRefresh outside of your build method. There is no reason to have it in there.

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similiar issue by calling the [setState method](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html) (notify the framework that the internal state of this object has changed).

Example here: https://googleflutter.com/flutter-add-item-to-listview-dynamically/

Answer (score 1):

I think who reading this answer try to update all list of `ListView` lump sum, by replace old list with new one, the problem happen if old list similar to  new one in most values, I solved this problem temporarily in the following way:

```
setState(() => _currentList.clear());
Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 50), () {
  setState(() => _currentList.addAll(_newList));
});
```

You can show [CircularProgressIndicator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/CircularProgressIndicator-class.html) during the 50 milliseconds.

> Note: if elements of current list are not the same as the elements of
> the new list and its has completely different, you will not face this
> problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the key for your custom widget, like the following:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext ctx, int index) {
  Manga manga = _listContent[index];
  return new MangaItem(
    name: manga.writtenName,
    number: manga.currentNr,
    state: false,
    key: Key(index.toString())
  );
}),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).