# Flutter not retrieving variable new value while calling in another class

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have this StatefulWidget that supposed to retrieve data from MySQL database based on condition and add those retrieved values into an array so I can use the array values to be display on ListView. My Problem is that sometimes when the array (`_fileValues`) and `_custUsername` variable are either empty or not updated and no exception is thrown.

Here's my statefulwidget (`main.dart`)

```
String? _custUsername;
List<String> _fileValues = <String>[];

class cakeLogin extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  cakeLoginPageMain createState() => cakeLoginPageMain(); 
}

class cakeLoginPageMain extends State<cakeLogin> {

  String? _CustEmailInit; 
  BuildContext? loginContext;

  List<String> _fileNameStores = <String>[];

  void callData() {
    // @ Get username based on user email and assign it to _custUsername variable
    UsernameGetter().Connection(_CustEmailInit!).then((UsernameValue) {
      _custUsername = UsernameValue!;
    });
    
    // @ Get item names based on the user username (_custUsername) and add them into
    // _fileNameStores
    NameGetter().Connection(_custUsername).then((NamesValues) {
      for(var _nameItems in NamesValues) {
        setState(() {
          _fileNameStores.add(_nameItems);
        });
      }
    });
    // @ Remove duplicates value and add them into main list (_fileValues)
    var _removeDuplicates = _fileNameStores.toSet().toList();
    for(var item in _removeNamesDupes) {
      setState(() {
       _fileValues.add(item);
      });
     }

  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final _emailController = TextEditingController();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Login to App",
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 18,
            color: setupFontCol,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
          )),
        backgroundColor: setupThemeBar,
        centerTitle: true,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        )
      ),
      backgroundColor: setupMainTheme,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: _emailController,
              style: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 214, 213, 213)),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                ),
                filled: true,
                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color.fromARGB(255, 197, 197, 197)),
                hintText: "Enter your email",
                fillColor: setupThemeBar
              ),
            ),

           SizedBox(height: 18),

           SizedBox(height: 25),

          SizedBox(
            height: 45,
            width: 500,
            child: ElevatedButton(
              style: 
                ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: setupFontCol,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  )
                ),
              onPressed: () {

                var _CustEmail = _emailController.text;

                if(_CustEmail.contains("@gmail.com") || _CustEmail.contains("@email.com")) {
                   if(_CustEmail != "") {
                          _CustEmailInit = _CustEmail;
                          loginContext = context;

                          _isFromLogin = true;
  
                          _fileValues.clear();
                          callData();

                    } else {
                      alertDialog("Please enter your email address",context);
                    }
                } else {
                    alertDialog("Email address is not valid",context);
                }
              },
              //color: setupFontCol,
              child: Text("Login",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ))
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),      
    );
  }
}
```

`UsernameGetter` class (This class will retrieve user Username from database table based on their email from textfield input)

When I print `_usernameDetected` from `UsernameGetter` class it returns the updated version of the returned string but when I assign the `_custUsername` to `UsernameValue` from `main.dart` it does not update and sometimes it returns null value.

```
import 'package:mysql_client/mysql_client.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:signuppage/main.dart' as main;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class UsernameGetter {
  Future<String> Connection(String _custEmail) async {
    final conn = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
      host: "",
      port: ,
      userName: "",
      password: "",
      databaseName: "",
    );

    await conn.connect();

    var _getUsernameQue = await conn.execute("SELECT CUST_USERNAME FROM information WHERE CUST_EMAIL = :email", 
    {
      "email": _custEmail
    });

    String? _usernameDetected;
    for(final _rowsOfEmail in _getUsernameQue.rows) {
      _usernameDetected = _rowsOfEmail.assoc()['CUST_USERNAME']!;
    }
    return await _usernameDetected!;
  }
}
```

`NameGetter` class (Retrieve user items names which are stored in text column)

For `NameGetter` class the same case happens as `UsernameGetter`. When I retrieve the values from `main.dart` and add the values into `_fileValues` list sometimes the values is empty and sometimes the value is not updated.

```
import 'package:mysql_client/mysql_client.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:ffi';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:signuppage/main.dart' as main;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class NameGetter {

  Future<List<String>> Connection(String _custUsername) async {
    final conn = await MySQLConnection.createConnection(
      host: "",
      port: ,
      userName: "",
      password: "",
      databaseName: "",
    );
    await conn.connect();

    var _getItemNames= await conn.execute("SELECT ITEM_NAMES FROM item_details WHERE CUST_USERNAME = :username",
      {
        "username": _custUsername
      });

    List<String>? _itemNamesValues= <String>[]; 
    for(var _rowsOfItemNames in _getItemNames.rows) {
      var _retrieveNames = await _rowsOfItemNames.assoc()['ITEM_NAMES']!;
      _itemNamesValues.add(_retrieveNames);
    }

    return await _itemNamesValues;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where's my mistakes is and I'm pretty sure I made a lot of mistake and I need someone to help me figure it out. Especially on why the list and the variable are not updated/and is sometimes empty.

Refer links:

[Flutter ListView not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648784/flutter-listview-not-)

[my list in flutter is not updating the problem in my code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71958465/my-list-in-flutter-is-not-updating-the-problem-in-my-code)

[Why variable value is not refreshing in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60285355/why-variable-value-is-not-refreshing-in-flutter)

Comment: Your code implies that you have null safety disabled. I strongly encourage you to run with null safety to catch issues before runtime. In any case, `_custUsername` is set from the result of a Future. However, you are using `_custUsername` potentially before it has been assigned, in the call to `NameGetter().Connection(_custUsername)`. You might consider refactoring `callData()` to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: So you mean I have to get rid of `then` statement and replace it with `async/await` instead? if yes then i've tried that but I gets lost and not sure how to properly implement it. Can you provide an example on Answer how to implement async/await for my case?

Comment: You don't *have* to, but it will be easier to understand the flow of code if you do. Added an answer with an example refactor of `callData()` using `async`/`await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

A stripped down version of your `callData()` method looks like this:

```dart
  var foo;

  void callData() {
    someAsyncFunction().then( ... foo = value ... );
    anotherAsyncFunction(foo).then( ... );
  }
```

As written, `anotherAsyncFunction(foo)` is called immediately following `someAsyncFunction()`, *before* the `then()` which assigns the value of `foo`.

You can observe this behavior for yourself by strategically inserting `print()` statements.

### The Solution

Under the hood, `Future.then()` and `async`/`await` are the same thing. However, it is generally easier for folks to reason about the behavior of asynchronous code when using `async`/`await`, because then it reads like sequentially executed code.

Although you can use either, I suggest that you move to `async`/`await` to make the code easier to follow when reading.

Here's one example of how you might refactor `callData()`:

```dart
  Future<void> callData() async {
    // @ Get username based on user email and assign it to _custUsername variable
    var custUsername = await UsernameGetter().Connection(_CustEmailInit!);
    
    // @ Get item names based on the user username (_custUsername) and add them into
    // _fileNameStores
    var namesValues = await NameGetter().Connection(custUsername);

    setState(() {
      _fileNameStores.addAll(namesValues);
      // @ Remove duplicates value and add them into main list (_fileValues)
      _fileValues.addAll(_fileNameStores.toSet());
    });
  }
```

Written this way, it is plainly clear that `custUsername` is assigned before the call to `NameGetter().Connection(custUsername)`.

Be sure to read through [Asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await).

Comment: You saved me from being neurotics!!!! thank you brother.